# Rules da Classe request do Laravel validar delete

Tags: laravel-5.3, delete

No [`Laravel 5.3`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/releases) existe alguma forma de usar as `rules` das classes [`request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) para não deixar um registro do banco que tenha relacionamento ser excluído?

Parecido com a regra que não deixa um registro ser inserido duplicado.